# Django - Logout Redirect to Login Page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am trying to redirect to login page after logout but some issues are coming.

```
urls.py
```

This is my actual logout routes and it works for me but it does not redirect me to login page

```
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

Changing logout.html -> login.html

It destroys the session and logout the user but the problem is that when i click logout it redirects to login page but login input fields are not showing

```
 path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='logout'),
```

And if i am using below path(route). It is not destroying session nor logout

```
path('login/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='logout'),
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add in you settings file

`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/'`

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url

Also Changing logout.html -> login.html, is not required please revert it back

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Before doing anything, make sure to import

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
```

Then, you can do this

```
path('/logout', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout')
```

You can define the login URL in settings.py like @`nagesh` mentioned.

There's another way to handle this and specially, comes handy when you have `logout` buttons at multiple places and you want the user to land to different pages after clicking different logout buttons in your interface.

```
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
    next_page=reverse_lazy('Userauth:login') # you can use your named URL here just like you use the **url** tag in your django template
), name='logout'),
```

I suggest that you use `reverse_lazy` to define the redirect URL, it can create dynamic URL very easily and you don't have to worry if you ever change your URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to list my account/user application above admin.

before

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'account.apps.AccountConfig'
```

after

```
'account.apps.AccountConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views from django.urls import path, 
reverse_lazy
```

Then do this

```
path('/logout', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout') You can define the 
login URL in settings.py like @nagesh mentioned.
```

To this

```
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view( 
next_page=reverse_lazy('login') # you can use your named URL here just 
like you use the url tag in your django template ), name='logout'),
```