# LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL doesn't redirect to the desired page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm new to Django and run to the problem that I want to logout from an account by one click using 'django.contrib.auth.urls'.
Here is my 'urls.py'

```
path("accounts/", include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

home.html

```
{%  if user.is_authenticated %}
     <p>Hi, {{ user.username }}</p>
     <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></p>          
{% else %}
     <p>You are not logged in</p>
     <p><a href="{% url 'login'  %}">Log In</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

settings.py

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
```

I know that by default I should be redirected to /accounts/logout, when I click on href link, but I set LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL to home. LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home" on the other hand works perfectly
I read a lot of topics on this problem but none of the solutions helped me

I tried setting path manually. It worked in a sense that it I stayed at the same page, but I didn't log out from my account

```
path('', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page=settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL), name='logout'),
```

Comment: Why is your LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL the same?

Comment: Since I want to redirect on the same page after log in and out. Like if u click log out, u just stay at the same page

Comment: there's no such thing as being an 'is_authenticated' page, you logout and stay on the same page. Your issue is in the way you're defining the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL routes in your settings.py file.

Comment: Unless the nature of your site is such that it has a landing page,  and that users can login while still on the landing page and even logout without leaving the page.  Because you say you're only new to Django, I'll imagine you're not doing this. I'll point you to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url and to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002774/django-logout-redirect-to-login-page

Comment: What happens when you click "Log out"? You only told what happens when you set the `next_page` manually. Do you receive an error? I think it is fine to let both views redirect to the same page.

Comment: When I click log out I’m being redirected to the ../accounts/logout url which was not defined by me(it’s how django works, I believe), but in a book that I read setting LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL changes url where web app goes after clicking log out

Answer (score 0):

We must be using the same book, @user23355404.

There was a change with Django 5, and that technique of logging out no longer works. You need need to use a form and do a "post". The change was identified in this [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/35063)

Will Vincent (book author) also explains the change and how to fix it at this [site](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial).

You need to change your logout process to:

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Log Out</button
</form>
```

You will now see a Log Out button rather than a link. I've tested this and it works for me. I hope that helps.